# Подпись JS скриптов при подключении (Защита от модификации)

Tags: javascript, html

Где-то видел защиту при подключении скриптов от модификации, выглядело примерно так

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{url}" hash="{script hash}"></script>
```

Работало это так: создавался хэш подключаемого файла и указывался в соответствующее поле, браузер, перед подключением скрипта сверял хэши и в случае модификации файла не подключал его, выбрасывая ошибку в консоль.

Видел такое, если не ошибаюсь, при подключении jQuery через какой-то CDN.

Как правильно это гуглить, какое имя атрибута на самом деле и какая подпись используется?

Comment: [Ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29270598/specifying-the-hash-of-a-script-from-an-untrusted-host?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). Но учтите, что это пока только Chrome-based и FF.

Comment: @ПерцевРоман если это единственное решение - оформляйте как ответ, отмечу как решение

Comment: @ПерцевРоман в других браузерах атрибут signature будет проигнорирован или это не валидно? Если первое, то всё в порядке, меня не волнуют пользователи, которых не заботит собственная безопасность

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [Subresource Integrity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity), пример приведен [по ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29270598/specifying-the-hash-of-a-script-from-an-untrusted-host?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). Но учтите, что это пока только Chrome-based, Safari и FF, в остальных браузерах проигнорируется, пока не появится поддержки по [стандарту W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/SRI/). Для использования вам потребуется сгенерировать хэш ресурса по одному из алгоритомов: SHA-256, SHA-384 или SHA-512, и записать его в атрибут тега script

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://site53.example.net/style.css"
  integrity="sha256-vjnUh7+rXHH2lg/5vDY8032ftNVCIEC21vL6szrVw9M="
  crossorigin="anonymous" />
```

Для Webpack в наличии соответствующий плагин: https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-subresource-integrity, наверняка не один.

Comment: Перенеси суть ответа, а только ссылку.

Comment: Ну и с 2015 года прошло довольно много времени и поддержка довольно широка

Comment: @Grundy, поддержка на данный момент ограничена только FF, Safari и Chrome-based, к сожалению

Comment: Ты проверил? Или это цитата из ответа 2015 года? Если верить [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#feat=subresource-integrity) safari, chrome, ff, и edge (не сразу увидел, что там про будущую версию речь идет, но все равно)

Comment: @Grundy я сначала посмотрел MDN, там только Chrome и FF. И потом уже на Caniuse